# Percentage of body weight raised for this variation of pull ups?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, everyday-life, estimation

I have a simple question I think.
If one uses one [dip bar](https://www.amazon.com/dip-bar/s?k=dip%20bar) and do a version of pull ups as follows:
[image]

what percentage of their body weight is lifted? I.e. how different is it than a regular pull up in a pull up bar?
Note that the feet are held straight and are swapping the floor as the arms bring the upper chest close to the bar.
The height of the bar is ~45% of the body

Answer (score 0):

It depends how far the COM of the body is raised.

The work done in a regular pull-up is $mgh$ where $m$ is the mass of the body and $h$ is the distance raised - that's about an arm length, about $2/3$ the height of the bar.

For the pull up in the diagram, the COM of the body seems to be raised from about $1/6$ the height of the bar to $1/2$ the height of the bar, so the difference is about $1/3$ the height of the bar.

So approximately we are comparing the $2/3$ bar height to $1/3$.

So about $1/2$ of the work is done compared to a regular pull-up.

You'll know the accurate measurements to make it more accurate, you might also want to include work done against friction on the floor depending on how significant you judge it to be.

Comment: What is  COM? Also the diagram is not accurate in regards to distances. What should I measure?

Comment: The diagram is not to scale

Comment: @ Jim, Centre Of Mass, the measurements were from your link too and made as accurate as possible using the things in the question.  Just ask someone to measure how much a point (approximately where a belt would) be gets raised for each type, then divide the distances, that tells you how many times more work is done by regular compared to the one in the question...all the best with it.

Comment: The issue is that when trying it, if it was indeed 1/2 of a pull up it would feel much lighter (I can do many reps in a machine with half my weight) but in reality, I can only do just 1 may be 2 more reps than what I do with a regular pull up. So I think I might have not stated something correctly?

Comment: Also what is `g` in the `mgh`?

Comment: @ Jim g=9.8  it's the acceleration due to gravity.  If the friction on the floor is high the work done for each pull up would also include about $\mu\times 0.5mgd$ where $\mu$ is to do with how slippery the floor is, $0$ for very smooth and slippery, $1$ for very rough and not slippery.  and $d$ is the distance that your feet dragged.  Hope you can use these things to estimate what you need.

Comment: What is the `0.5`? Also if the floor is very smooth, and `` is 0 then the multiplication makes everything 0. Is that correct?

Comment: yes it makes sense. Only the `0.5` I am not clear how did it appear. I suppose is the `1/2` of work you mention?

Comment: @ Jim it's an approximation that half the weight is on the arms and half supported by the upward force at the feet $N$, then from $F=\mu N$, $F=0.5mg\times \mu$, all the best with it.